# Error: crossprod(t(X), beta) in panel study

Tags: r, panel, plm

I am working on a panel study project (in R) and encountered the following error(s) when creating a within fixed effect:

```
within5 <- plm(Y~X1*X3+X8+X9, data=pdata2, model = "within")
summary(within5)
```

Here `X8` and `X9` are control variables (but they contain missing values)
The error I receive is:

> crossprod(t(X), beta) :non-conformable arguments

Any advice?

When working with dummy fixed effects, I receive the following error:

```
dummy5 <- plm(Y ~ X1*X3+X8+X9+(factor(country)-1), data=pdata2,
              model = "pooling")
```

> Error: Error in xj[i, , drop = FALSE] : (subscript) bolesh Index too long

Comment: Thanks for any help!

Comment: What programming language or software are you using?

Comment: The software I am using is R

Comment: Chances are, your variables are linear dependent (maybe after dropping of NA values and/or the within transformation). There is a convenient function called `detect_lin_dep` in the `plm` package (only in the development version, see https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=406) to check for linear dependent variables; the help for that function is quite extensive.